# Find minimum distance and update column with PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I need help in my PostGIS database to calculate the distance between two points.
The goal is to find for each row in the "Dots" table the distance from the closest point in the  "reflayer" points table and save it in meter in the "dist_from_ref" column.

The dots table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE dots
(
    dot_id INT,
    site_id INT,
    latitude float ( 6 ),
    longitude float ( 6 ),
    rsrp float ( 6 ),
    dist INT,
    project_id INT,
    dist_from_site INT,
    geom geometry,
    dist_from_ref INT;
);
```

The reflayer structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE reflayers 
(
    layer_name varchar,
    latitude float ( 6 ),
    longitude float ( 6 ) ,
    geom geometry
);
```

Dots table

[image: Dots table]

Reflayer table

[image: Reflayer table]

Does anyone have a solution that can update the "dist_from_ref" column with the minimal distance the query can find?

Edit:

```
UPDATE dots d
SET dist_from_ref = 100 * ROUND (1000 * ST_Distance(d.geom, r.geom))
FROM reflayers r 
WHERE d.dist_from_ref IS NULL 
  AND r.geom = (SELECT r.geom
                FROM reflayers r 
                ORDER BY ST_Distance(d.geom, r.geom) ASC LIMIT 1);
```

This query updates the columns as I want to, but it stuck on my PostGIS server with 60K rows.

I used it on 70 rows and I worked fine any suggestions to improve it?

Before and After

Dots table before

[image: Dots Table Before]

Dots table after

[image: Dots Table After]

Text table

```
dot_id | site_id | latitude  | longitude |  rsrp  | project_id | dist_from_site | dist_from_ref |                        geom
--------+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+------------+----------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------
      1 |   42047 | 31.902857 | 34.919445 |  -90.9 |          1 |             21 |          7200 | 0101000020E6100000F5F6E7A221E73F4041BCAE5FB0754140
      2 |   42047 | 31.902857 | 34.919445 |  -89.5 |          1 |             21 |          7200 | 0101000020E6100000F5F6E7A221E73F4041BCAE5FB0754140
      3 |   42047 | 31.902857 | 34.919445 |  -89.5 |          1 |             21 |          7200 | 0101000020E6100000F5F6E7A221E73F4041BCAE5FB0754140
```

Comment: in your query you refer to sites  but in your question you refer to reflayer  table .. could be you have posted  the wrong query..

Comment: Please don't add tags for database that are not relevant.

Comment: @Vlad_Gesin would this be what you're looking for? `SELECT *,(
  SELECT min(ST_Distance(d.geom, r.geom))
  FROM reflayers r)
FROM dots d` . Next time also post the sample data as text (not images) and also let us know what is the exact expected result. This saves us all a lot of time and effort :) cheers

Comment: Thank you I have been updated my question with pictures and the query.

Comment: @Vlad_Gesin does the query I posted return the expected results? As I mentioned in my last comment, tt would be nice to have the data sample as text, not images. Btw, an update could look like this: `UPDATE dots SET dist_from_ref = (
  SELECT min(ST_Distance(dots.geom, r.geom))
  FROM reflayers r)`

Comment: Works perfectly on a small table, on the 50K stuck...

Comment: On a side note, the distance you have computed is garbage because it assumes a degree of longitude has the same ground length as a degree of latitude, which is not the case. Use [https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DistanceSphere.html](ST_DistanceSphere) instead.

Comment: Thank you for noticing me, but I change my code to measure the distance now from point to polygon, much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the subquery in the `SELECT` clause and reference it to the each row of the outer query, e.g.

```
SELECT *,(
  SELECT min(ST_Distance(d.geom, r.geom))
  FROM reflayers r) as distance
FROM dots d;
```

To update just do the same ..

```
UPDATE dots SET dist_from_ref = (
  SELECT min(ST_Distance(dots.geom, r.geom))
  FROM reflayers r)
```

**Note**: Depending on the table size this operation can become very time consuming. Since you have no way to join both tables, you let the query run a full scan in every single record of `refLayers` for every single record on `dots` in order to find the closest distance.

Comment: Works perfectly on a small table stuck on the big one.
The 50K rows take about 7 mins.

Comment: @Vlad_Gesin is there any way to perform a join with these tables or another column in the where clause to sort of reduce the amount of records? This would significantly reduce the query time.

Comment: I don't have anything in common with the reflayer and dots tables.

Comment: @Vlad_Gesin in that case I believe you'll have to wait a bit longer ;) just let the query run. One option to avoid a full scan would be to `ST_DWithin` the records in the inner query with a buffer that makes sense to your use case, but it would dangerously smell like a bad workaround ;)